# Unity On-Demand Resolve of Interfce Properties

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, unity-container, dependency-resolver

I have an interface `IRDFReport` and a base class `BaseReport` which implements that. The `View` and `Report` properties are heavy objects and should be resolving only when the report is actually being requested. I used two simple string suffix for finding named mappings of `View` and `Report` properties of the objects.

I'd like to use Unity to resolve heavy objects on demand while being able to resolve all reports to have a list of them. Is this kind of resolving in `get` methods the best I can do for this?

```
public interface IRDFReport
{
    UserControl View { get; }
    string ReportName { get; }
    string Name { get; set; }
    Task<bool> GenerateReport(SynchronizationContext context);
    DevExpress.XtraReports.IReport Report { get; set; }
}
```

`BaseReport` which implements this interface:

```
public class BaseReport : IRDFReport
{

    public DevX.IReport Report
    {
        get
        {
            return ReportManager.myContainer.Resolve<IReport>(ReportName + ReportManager.Report_Suffix) as XtraReport;
        }
    }

    public UserControl View
    {
        get
        {
            return ReportManager.myContainer.Resolve<UserControl>(ReportName + ReportManager.View_Suffix);
        }
    }

    ///
    /// other members
    ///
}
```

And in my report manager I register them like this:

```
public const string View_Suffix = ".View";
public const string Report_Suffix = ".XtraReport";

Reports = new List<IRDFReport>();

myContainer.RegisterType<IReport, BalanceSheetXtraReport>(nameof(BalanceSheetReport) + Report_Suffix, new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
myContainer.RegisterType<UserControl, BalanceSheetView>(nameof(BalanceSheetReport) + View_Suffix, new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());

  ///
  /// registering other reports inherited from BaseReport
  ///

myContainer.RegisterTypes(
    AllClasses.FromLoadedAssemblies()
    .Where(type => typeof(IRDFReport).IsAssignableFrom(type)),
    WithMappings.FromAllInterfaces,
    WithName.TypeName);

var reports = myContainer.ResolveAll<IRDFReport>().Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.Name)).ToList();
Reports.AddRange(reports);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are doing is called Service Location and [is considered an anti-pattern](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorisanAnti-Pattern/).

I am going to suggest a different way to obtain your dependency. Please note that I am going to provide some generic code just as an example. And also I am going to speak about `IReport` only. The other dependency can be treated similarly.

What I am suggesting is to use Constructor Injection. Your `BaseReport` has a dependency on `IReport`, but it want to be able to obtain it (and to have it constructed) only later on demand.

One way to do this is to use an [abstract factory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern).

Here is some example:

```
public interface IReportFactory
{
    IReport Create(); //this can also take parameters
}
```

You can then create an implementation of this factory and inject it to the constructor of `BaseReport`. This will enable `BaseReport` to request the `IReport` dependency on demand.

Another solution is to use the .NET [Lazy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642331(v=vs.110).aspx) class. This class allows you to create the dependency on the first time your try to use it. Unity has native support for the `Lazy` class (see [this reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn507482(v=pandp.30).aspx)).

Here is an example on how you would use it:

You can inject `Lazy<IReport>` into your `BaseReport` class like this:

```
public class BaseReport
{
    private readonly Lazy<IReport> m_LazyReport;

    public BaseReport(Lazy<IReport> lazy_report)
    {
        m_LazyReport = lazy_report;
    }

    public IReport Report
    {
        get { return m_LazyReport.Value; }
    }
}
```

In the [Composition Root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/) (the place where you use the DI container), do the following:

```
UnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();

container.RegisterType<IReport, Report>("name");

container.RegisterType<BaseReport>(
    new InjectionConstructor(
        new ResolvedParameter<Lazy<IReport>>("name")));
```

It is enough to just register `IReport`, and then Unity can resolve `Lazy<IReport>` without any problem, and it knows to make it work in such a way that only when the `Lazy` object value is accessed that it goes ahead and creates the `Report` object.

Comment: Thanks @YacoubMassad. The `Lazy<T>` did the trick to resolve on-demand. Now I have constructor injections for both `View` and `Report` properties.